# Error while deploying a WCF service on web

Tags: wcf, deployment, hosting

I created a working WCF Service Library on my computer.

When I published it on the hosting (right-click -> Publish -> I entered address) and launched the web page with this service like ".../webservice.svc"

I received such an error:

[image]

What was wrong?

What should I change to make it work?

Comment: <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />

Comment: I do not have "web.config" file in my project, only "app.config" file (I have WCF Service Library Project)

Comment: Try to open http://localhsot/webservice.svc on your hosting box - then you will get more information.

Comment: In localhost/webservice.svc it opens correctly...

Comment: I added WCF Service Application to my project, added WCF Service Library as a reference, published and now it works!
But I can not understand why it doesn't work in the case of publishin WCF Service Library...

Comment: What is the error that you see? It's not mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is essential to turn on the error message to see what is the error itself.
After I turned on the error messages in the WCF service configuration file, I saw the problem and fixed it. It was a problem with one of the libraries.